Mean curvature flow: Second time derivative?
Suppose I have a 2D surface in $\mathbb R^3$ undergoing mean curvature flow, i.e., the motion of a point on the surface instantaneously can be described as $$\frac{d\mathbf x}{dt}=-H\mathbf n,$$ where $H$ is mean curvature and $\mathbf n$ is the outward surface normal.
Is there a nice formula for the second derivative $\frac{d^2\mathbf x}{dt^2}$, e.g. in terms of the principal curvatures/directions and surface normal?
More generally, is there a clean technique for deriving such formulas for gradient flows, essentially by differentiating both sides of the PDE in time?  I'd love to find a similar formula for Willmore/Ricci flow and other flows.

There is a formula. First find the formulas for $\partial_tH, \partial_t\mathbf{n}$. Differentiate the mean curvature flow equation and substitute in the formulas you found in the first step.

Of course this is what to do.  I'm left with a gigantic pile of symbols, so I was sort of hoping there might be a pointer to an elegant formula/derivation.  Apologies if my question was not worded carefully enough.

The formulas are in section 3 of Huisken's paper (which is the first major study of the mean curvature flow. https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-20/issue-1/Flow-by-mean-curvature-of-convex-surfaces-into-spheres/10.4310/jdg/1214438998.full.
